# Sharepoint Rest API: Create Folder Columns and set values for items

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am looking for documentation to manage folder columns and ability to create the columns if not exists on the folder and set the values of these columns on the item using SharePoint REST APIs.

`_api/web/GetFolderById(guid'<>')` gets me the folder.

But how to get the columns on the folder and how to create/update for items?

If anyone can point me to the documentation for all this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Found how pasting here if someone faces the same issue.

```
_api/web/GetFolderById(guid'<UniqueId>')}')/Properties
```

using the property `vti_x005f_listid`:

```
_api/web/lists(guid'<list_id>')/Fields
```

to create field use same as above using POST, make sure the headers below

```
"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
"Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"

{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Field"
  },
  "Title": "field title",
  "FieldTypeKind": 2, //single line 
  "Required": "true/false",
  "EnforceUniqueValues": "true/false",
  "StaticName": "field name"
}
```

using the file as list item you can update the value similar to as you do with  listitem.GetItemByUniqueId which can be retrieved from the file.